# Find string that appears in an array of string's array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays

```
const arr = [
    ['foo', 'bar', 'hey', 'oi'], 
    ['foo', 'bar', 'hey'], 
    ['foo', 'bar', 'anything'],
    ['bar', 'anything']
]
```

I'm trying to get the strings that appears in all arrays, which in this case only `bar`.

I tried a lot of things with `.filter` but all looks confusing.

Is there a simple solution find a string that appear in all arrays?

## Edit:

What I have tried

```js
const arr = [
    ['foo', 'bar', 'hey', 'oi'], 
    ['foo', 'bar', 'hey'], 
    ['foo', 'bar', 'anything'],
    ['bar', 'anything']
]

const keySet = new Set()
arr.forEach(x => x.forEach(y => keySet.add(y)))

const uniqueKeys = Array.from(keySet)

console.log(uniqueKeys)

const res = uniqueKeys.filter(x => !arr.some(y => !y.includes(x)))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: I'd build an object to map each string to a count of source arrays it appears in. Then you'd just need to find the strings that appear in `arr.length` sub-arrays.

Comment: What is the output supposed to look like?

Comment: @VLAZ as said in the question `I'm trying to get the string that appears in all arrays, which in this case only bar.`

Comment: @Vencovsky to me that doesn't tell me what you're looking for. A simple string? An array with one string in it? An array with as many strings as you have sub-arrays which include the string in the original array? An array with as many *elements* as the original array but they can be either the string or something like `undefined`/`null` if the string is not found within a given sub-array?

Comment: After the edit: the initial question was not at all clear to me that you wanted to *dynamically* find a string. I understood that you wanted to search *by a string* in the sub-arrays.

Comment: @VLAZ The only problem with my question was that I didn't provided what I have tried in the first time and took too much time to edit. Is now better? Or is something missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in two steps:

- Apply `filter()` on the first element of the array.(You can use an element)
- Inside `filter()` use `every()` or the original array and check if that element is present in all the arrays.

```js
const arr = [
    ['foo', 'bar', 'hey', 'oi'], 
    ['foo', 'bar', 'hey'], 
    ['foo', 'bar', 'anything'],
    ['bar', 'anything']
]

const res = arr[0].filter(x => arr.every(a => a.includes(x)));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: you dont need the `[... new Set(arr.flat())]` you can just do `arr[0].filter(x => arr.every(a => a.includes(x)))`

Comment: @nickzoum Oh yeah. I completely forgot this things. Thanks.

Comment: @nickzoum why? Could you explain that please

Comment: @Vencovsky Because if the element is present in each array. Then it must be also present in first array. You can say it like. If the element is present in all the arrays then it must be present in the first array.

Comment: @MaheerAli Thanks, nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the arrays by filtering with a `Set`.

```js
const
    array = [['foo', 'bar', 'hey', 'oi'], ['foo', 'bar', 'hey'], ['foo', 'bar', 'anything'], ['bar', 'anything']],
    common = array.reduce((a, b) => a.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(b)));

console.log(common);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use combination of `reduce` and `filter` to get the intersection between all arrays:

```js
const res = arr.reduce((acc, a) => acc.filter(value  => a.includes(value) ), arr[0])
```

If you use `lodash`, the code would be simpler though:

```js
const _ = require('lodash');
const res = _.intersection(...arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter()`, `.flat()` and `.every()`.

```js
const arr = [
  ['foo', 'bar', 'hey', 'oi'],
  ['foo', 'bar', 'hey'],
  ['foo', 'bar', 'anything'],
  ['bar', 'anything']
];

var flat = arr.flat();
//▼ filters through the words to see which ones are all included
console.log(flat.filter(v => arr.every(a => a.includes(v)))
                .filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i));
                //▲ filter through the 4 bars to get only one
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the first solution I could come up with, see if it's ok for you:

```
const arr = [
    ['foo', 'bar', 'hey', 'oi'], 
    ['foo', 'bar', 'hey'], 
    ['foo', 'bar', 'anything'],
    ['bar', 'anything']
];

const result = [];

arr[0].forEach(str => {
    let present = true;
    arr.slice(1).forEach(array => {
        if (!array.includes(str))
            present = false;
        });
    if (present)
        result.push(str);
});
```

Answer (score -4):

> Use .filter like :

```
 const arr = [
       str: {'foo', 'bar',
              'hey', 'oi'}, 
       str: {'foo', 'bar', 
'hey'}, 
       str: {'foo', 'bar', 
'anything'},
       str: {'bar',
 'anything'}
    ]
    const result = arr.filter((arr) => arr.str === bar)

    console.log(result)

    //gives you bar lines
```

Comment: You've changed the data from the question, and the point is that the value 'bar' won't be known, so you can't search / check against it